# How to dynamically define each hyperlink as the linked slides change in PowerPoint 2016

Tags: vba, hyperlink, powerpoint

There is a hyperlink on the first slide to another slide in the same presentation. The other slides contain detail, and since the size of the detail changes, the position of the slide changes as well. One time the hyperlink would need to go to slide 8 the next time to slide 9. The detail slides are a cut and paste from a pdf, and the current fix is to manually adjust each hyperlink. The text on the hyperlink is the same as the header for the detail slide, so I’m hoping there is a way to dynamically define each hyperlink as the linked slides change. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear (perhaps just to me) whether you want to link to a particular slide regardless of how many slides are added or deleted before or after it, or you want to link to a slide with a given heading, even though the original slide with that heading may have been deleted. The first case is how PowerPoint works. The second case ...?  PowerPoint doesn't work that way. True, the link includes the slide title (if any) but it also includes the SlideID; that's the primary thing PPT looks for when following a link.

Comment: Thanks for the response  @SteveRindsberg, let me see if I can clarify. Detail slides are deleted, then new ones pasted in, so the links to the first slide (which is  never deleted) can possibly be wrong. I’m looking for a way to re-create or change the links without having to go into each one to manually.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. In theory (and in my experience, in practice) what you're doing shouldn't cause the link to break.